# Extract values from attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery selectors. How can I extract the values from an attribute?

Given:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='entry' data-name='foo'></div>
<div class='entry' data-name='bar'></div>
<div class='entry' data-name='baz'></div>
</div>
```

I'd want to extract:
`['foo','bar','baz']`

Comment: I had expected to be able to iterate through something like jQuery('.entry')[0].attr('data-name') but that doesn't seem to work. Nor does jQuery('.entry')[0].attributes.data-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array from a set of dom elements like

```
var array = $('.container .entry').map(function () {
    return $(this).data('name')
}).get();
```

Comment: @diEcho that depends on whether OP wants an array or a string... from `['foo','bar','baz']` it looks like OP wants an array

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$(function () {
    var array = [];
    $(".entry").each(function () {
        array.push($(this).data("name"));
    });
    console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
<div class='entry' data-name='foo'></div>
<div class='entry' data-name='bar'></div>
<div class='entry' data-name='baz'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var name = [];
$('div.container').children().map(function() {  
    name.push($(this).data('name'));
});
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m5r4n3sa/)

Comment: If you're using `map` no need to create an `array` variable

Comment: `name` is an array varaible